# how to link yarn@v3 package for my yarn@v1 project

Tags: frontend, yarnpkg

my project used yarn@v1, I can link another package with `yarn link` and `yarn link xxx`.
but now i have a dependence managed by yarn@v3, i can not use `yarn link` in this package link it to the global, how to work with yarn@v1 link and yarn@v3 link ?

Maybe should upgrade the yarn to v3 ?

Comment: Did you have to update the v1 project in order to link it? Or could you solve it otherwise? I am currently facing the same problem.